# how to excute powershell script on remote machine using ssh in python

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, ssh

When I ssh to the windows machine it will not be in powershell prompt and I don't know how I'm going to execute the powershell script I have.

I tried the following code without success.

```
ssh_connect(ip1, " powershell.exe <mtu-read.ps1")

def ssh_connect(address, script):

    #key_filename1 = 'id_rsa' #no authentication for now testing
    host_user = "Administrator"
    try:
        process1 = subprocess.Popen("ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no " + host_user + "@" + address + script, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        output1 = process1.stdout.readlines()
        print(output1)
        return output1

    except Exception as er2:
        print(str(er2) + ' connection issue ')
        return "0"
```

The result I get is that it does not recognize the command in the powershell.

Comment: Honestly, the best way to do this is to have the python script download powershell as a string and execute it using IEX. You can host your powershell script on a webserver and serve it like that.

Comment: @AlexanderSinno It really isn't.  Using `Invoke-Expression` should be for very select use-cases.  The issue is OP's use of `<`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid in the [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) call:

```
powershell.exe -File mtu-read.ps1
```

Note your working directory or the script file won't be found.  I suggest fully-qualifying your script path as a best-practice.

---

As an aside, I question why you're using [python](/questions/tagged/python) to execute [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) instead of just writing a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script and utilizing [winrm](/questions/tagged/winrm) (native to Windows) instead of [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh).

Comment: the files are not in the server i should point out that i wanted to feed them to the ssh connection using <

Comment: @nadeem You can't.  You'd need to read the file content and use the `-Command` argument in that scenario while also dealing with all the `cmd` escaping rules.  Alternatively, use base64 and `-EncodedCommand`

Comment: "OpenSSH has been added to Windows as of autumn 2018, and is included in Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019." [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview)